How to prevent page scrolling when dragging over the viewport edges
When dragging things on the edge of an overflowing page, the page will start scrolling. How to prevent this behavior with native browser functions / styling? It's OK to work only on Firefox. (I'm writing some userChrome.js script)
For example, open www.wikipedia.org, when there is a vertical scrollbar (which the full page size is larger than the viewport, aka overflowing), if you drag a file from desktop, folder, or whatever onto the top or bottom edge of the viewport, the page will start scrolling. I want to prevent that.
I've tried calling event.preventDefault() on the dragover event, but it does not work. Using overflow:hidden can stop it, but I need the page to be scrollable (at least visually). I'm thinking to create a box that with 0 width but only a scrollbar, then synchronize the scroll behavior of them to fake the users, but I'm wondering is there an elegant way.
P.S. Currently, during the dragging, I'm using overflow:hidden to disable the scrolling behavior, and show a dummy overflow:auto box beside, of which the clientHeight, scrollHeight and scrollTop are in sync with the page.

There's quite a popular answer here. Perhaps that will work, when you combine it with the dragenter and dragleave events? I haven't tried it myself, but it looks promising.

@KIKOSoftware I've tried the demo listed in the answer, but it does not prevent the scrolling I mentioned.
